# "Pull to refresh" not loading page properly on Lightning Component

Tags: javascript

I've been building my first functional Lightning Component, and I'm doing some fun slideToggle/hide functionality using jQuery. However, whenever I do a "pull to refresh" on a mobile device or via /one/one.app, it seems to fail to do the afterScriptsLoaded command properly, and all my "hideable sections" are open.

Here's what it SHOULD look like on a pull-to-refresh refresh. (And it successfully looks this way on an F5 refresh on my browser using one/one.app):

[image: As it should be]

Then I hit one of the section headers and it successfully twists open:

[image: Twisted as it should be]

However, here's what it looks like currently when I do a pull-to-refresh:

[image: NOT as it should be]

And I can't hide these sections in this case.

Here's the custom component code:

```
    <aura:component controller="charLightningHelper" implements="force:appHostable">
    <ltng:require scripts="/resource/jQuery" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.jqueryLoaded}" />
    <ltng:require scripts="/resource/jQueryToggle"/>


    <aura:attribute name="resmeeting" type="Reservation_meeting__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="rmid" type="Id"/>
    <aura:attribute name="currentUser" type="User"/>
    <aura:attribute name="visible" type="Boolean" default="false" />

<!--    <div class="header">
        Logos here
    </div> -->

<!--    <div class="plotinfo">
        <table class="headerTable">
            <tr>
                <td class="col1"><strong>DEVELOPMENT</strong><br/>  {!v.resmeeting.Development__c}</td>
                <td class="col2"><strong>Plot</strong><br/>{!v.resmeeting.Plot_book__r.Plot__r.Name}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1"><strong>Customer</strong><br/>{!v.resmeeting.Plot_book__r.Client__r.PurchaserName__c}</td>
                <td class="col2"><strong>Sales Adviser </strong></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div> -->

        <h1><div class="heading">Reservation meetings: {!v.resmeeting.Name}</div></h1>
        <div class="twisty" id="yourReservation" onclick="{!c.toggleDiv}">
                YOUR RESERVATION
        </div>
        <div class="hideable" id="ccYourReservation">
            <table class="inputTable">
                <tr><td>Exchange of contracts/missives agreed: </td>    <td><ui:inputDate value="{!v.resmeeting.Exchange_of_contracts_missives_agreed__c}" click="{!c.updateObj}"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Confirmation of build stage: </td>              <td><ui:inputCheckbox value="{!v.resmeeting.Confirmation_of_build_stage__c}" click="{!c.updateObj}"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Indicative move in date: </td>                  <td><ui:inputDate value="{!v.resmeeting.Indicative_move_in_date__c}" click="{!c.updateObj}"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Purchase price confirmed: </td>                 <td><ui:inputCheckbox value="{!v.resmeeting.Purchase_price_confirmed__c}" click="{!c.updateObj}"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>PX Procedures explained: </td>                  <td><ui:inputCheckbox value="{!v.resmeeting.PX_Procedures_explained__c}" click="{!c.updateObj}"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Certification of ID and Funding Completed: </td><td><ui:inputCheckbox value="{!v.resmeeting.Certificate_of_ID_Funding_Completed__c}" click="{!c.updateObj}"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Deposit and refund policy explained: </td>      <td><ui:inputCheckbox value="{!v.resmeeting.Deposit_info_refund_policy_explained__c}" click="{!c.updateObj}"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Advise to instruct solicitor: </td>             <td><ui:inputCheckbox value="{!v.resmeeting.Advise_to_instruct_solicitor__c}" click="{!c.updateObj}"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data release form for IFA signed: </td>         <td><ui:inputCheckbox value="{!v.resmeeting.Date_release_form_for_IFA_signed__c}" click="{!c.updateObj}"/></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="twisty" id="optionsAndExtras" onclick="{!c.toggleDiv}">
            <div class="mashable">
                OPTIONS AND EXTRAS
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hideable" id="ccOptionsAndExtras">
            Advise of preseslected items: <ui:inputCheckbox value="{!v.resmeeting.Purchase_price_confirmed__c}" click="{!c.updateObj}"/><br/>

        </div>
        <div class="twisty" id="leasehold" onclick="{!c.toggleDiv}">
            <div class="mashable">
                MANAGEMENT / FACTOR
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hideable" id="ccLeasehold">
            Advise of preseslected items: <ui:inputCheckbox value="{!v.resmeeting.Purchase_price_confirmed__c}" click="{!c.updateObj}"/>
        </div>

        <div class="twisty" id="generalDetails" onclick="{!c.toggleDiv}">
            <div class="mashable">
                GENERAL DETAILS
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hideable" id="ccGeneralDetails">
            Advise of preseslected items: <ui:inputCheckbox value="{!v.resmeeting.Purchase_price_confirmed__c}" click="{!c.updateObj}"/>
        </div>

        <div class="twisty" id="customerJourney" onclick="{!c.toggleDiv}">
            <div class="mashable">
                CUSTOMER JOURNEY
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hideable" id="ccCustomerJourney">
            Advise of preseslected items: <ui:inputCheckbox value="{!v.resmeeting.Purchase_price_confirmed__c}" click="{!c.updateObj}"/>
        </div>

        <div class="twisty" id="otherFeatures" onclick="{!c.toggleDiv}">
            <div class="mashable">
                ANY OTHER FEATURES DISCUSSED
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hideable" id="ccOtherFeatures">
            Advise of preseslected items: <ui:inputCheckbox value="{!v.resmeeting.Purchase_price_confirmed__c}" click="{!c.updateObj}"/>
        </div>


</aura:component>
```

And here's my Component JS Controller code:

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        currentUser
        var action = component.get("c.getReservationMeeting");
        action.setParams({
            rmid : component.get("rmid")

        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(d) {
                component.set("v.resmeeting", d.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);


    },

    updateObj : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('Click');
        var newResMeeting = component.get("v.resmeeting");
        var action = component.get("c.saveResMeeting");
        console.log('have the action');
        action.setParams({
            "resMeeting": newResMeeting
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.resmeeting", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    toggleDiv : function(){
        console.log('toggleDiv'); 
        ('.THIS.hideable').hide();

        ('.THIS.twisty').click(function(){
           (this).next().slideToggle(50); 
        });


    },

    jqueryLoaded : function(component, event, helper){
        $(function(){
           console.log('jqueryLoaded'); 
           $('.hideable').hide();

            $('.twisty').click(function(){
               $(this).next().slideToggle(); 
            });
        });  
    } ,

    showHide: function(cmp) {
        var isVisible = cmp.get("v.visible"); 
        // toggle the visible value
        cmp.set("v.visible", !isVisible);
    }


})
```

Any thoughts?